# MVC Newbie: call stored procedure Dataset in view without Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dataset

I'm new to MVC, coming from a .NET Web forms background with C#. I'm working on a Magazine subscription app in MVC with Razor where I just need to populate text from a stored procedure in a few table cells within my view. I would like to accomplish this using datasets as that's how the application is currently set up. I just can't figure out how to call the stored procedure in my model class and that's where I need help. Here's what I have so far:

MagazineController.cs

```
public ActionResult GetUser()
{
    return PartialView("UserSubscription")
}
```

Model - Subscription.cs

```
Namespace Magazine_Portal.Models
{
    public class UserSubscription
    {
        public string UserName {get; set;}
        public string MagazineName {get; set;}
        public DateTime SubscriptionDate {get; set;}
    }
}
```

I have written the stored procedure (`MagazinePortalTransfer.GetUserDetails`) and it returns 3 columns that can have multiple rows, the 3 columns are "FullName", "MagazineName" and "Date". So I'm assuming I would need to write the stored procedure class referencing `IList` or am I wrong about that? My connection string is set up too, so that works.

My other question is how do I go about setting the table cell values in the View to display the text coming from the database? `@Html.DisplayFor('something')` or can connect the controller to the Model by referencing `using Magazine_Portal.Models` in my assembly, then use `@Model.obj` in my view?

Thanks in advance for any assistance, I'm for the most part trying to figure out how to successfully call the stored procedure and its values within the application. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

first your model in the view should be a collection. 
you can fill the collection in the action calling the view.

```
public ActionResult GetView (){
  var collection = MethodeToFillCollection();

  return View("ViewName", collection)

}
```